# How to simplify $P (X|Y, Z)$ when $X$ is independent of $Y$ but not $Z$?

Tags: probability, bayes

How do I simplify $P (X|Y, Z)$ if I know that $X$ is independent of $Y$ but not $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by independent is $P(X|Y \cap Z) = P(X|Z)$ then it follows from definition since $P(X|Y,Z) = P(X|Y \cap Z) = P(X|Z)$. In plainer language, $Y$ occurring or not carries no information beyond $P(X|Z)$.

See the Wikipedia page as indirectly suggested by Andy for more:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence

Comment: This is only true if $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$. Note that, although $X$ and $Y$ might me unconditionally independent, conditioning on $Z$ can turn that into a dependence.